# The method getText() is undefined for the type String

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь изучить запросы по http. Сейчас появляется одна ошибка

> The method `getText()` is undefined for the type String

Не могу понять почему:

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity {
    private static final String Login = "login";
    private static final String Password = "password";
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        final EditText account = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText loginIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        Button butlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        butlogin.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please wait, connecting to server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                try {
                    String accountValue = URLEncoder.encode(account.getText()
                            .toString(), "UTF-8");
                    String loginValue = URLEncoder.encode(loginIn.getText()
                            .toString(), "UTF-8");
                    String password = URLEncoder.encode(password.getText()
                            .toString(), "UTF-8");
                    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String URL = "http://" + accountValue + ".megaplan.ru/"
                            + loginValue + "&password" + password;
                    try {
                        String SetServerString = "";
                        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget,
                                responseHandler);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                } finally {
                }
            }});}}
```

Ошибка возникает в этой строчке:

```
String password = URLEncoder.encode(password.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас 2 переменных разных типов с одним и тем же именем

```
String passwordStr = URLEncoder.encode(password.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
```

должно работать